# Prove or disprove that $\phi(a^n - 1)$ is divisible by n

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I have a proof for the case of $a$ being prime I believe, I think this is also true for $a$ composite since I ran a test for the first $100$ numbers over the first $100$ values of $n$ and it seems to be true.

Anyway the proof for 'a' prime is indirect and through finite field theory. 
$ \phi(a^n - 1)$ is the number of primitive roots in $GF(a^n)$ and they have irreducible polynomials of degree n over $GF(a)$ and all the roots of that irreducible equation have to be primitive roots. So the irreducible equations partition the set of primitive roots into sets of $n$ elements which means $ \phi(a^n - 1)$ is divible by $n$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe this helps:
$$ (a , a^n - 1) = 1 $$ 
so

$$ a^{\Phi (a^n - 1)} = 1 \pmod {a^n-1} $$
on the other hand
$$ a^n = 1   \pmod {a^n-1} $$

Answer (score 7):

If $a > 1$ is an integer, then the order of $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{a^n-1}^*$ is $n$.

Answer (score 2):

We'll assume $a > 1$. Note that the order of $a$ modulo $(a^n-1)$ is *exactly* $n$:

- $a^n\equiv 1 \mod (a^n-1)$ (the order divides $n$)
- $|a^k - 1| < |a^n - 1|$ for $k<n$ (the order is at least $n$).

By Lagrange's Theorem, the order of an element divides the order of the group, thus:
$$n | \phi(a^n-1)$$