# Prove that $n$ devides $\phi(p^n-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Prove that $n$ devides $\phi(p^n-1)$ ($\phi(x)$ being the totient.)

I could not find anything about this particular question on the web, so I will share my argument here.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/331344/11619) or [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/339122/11619)(and probably many others on this site).

Comment: oh well, I guess my searching skills are weak.

Comment: Don't worry about that @foaly. It helped me a lot that I remembered this question being asked many times. It is easier to find something, when you know it is there. The local search function doesn't satisfactorily recognize TeX-commands, so it is often useless, if you don't know extra keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, observe that $\phi(p^n-1)$ is the order of the group of automorphisms of a cyclic group of order $p^n-1$. I.e.
$$\mid\Bbb{F}_{p^n}^*\mid=p^n-1$$
$$\mid Aut(\Bbb{F}_{p^n}^*)\mid=\phi(p^n-1)$$
$$Aut(\Bbb{F}_{p^n}^*)\ge Aut(\Bbb{F}_{p^n}/\Bbb{F}_p)=Gal(\Bbb{F}_{p^n}/\Bbb{F}_p)$$
$$\because Gal(\Bbb{F}_{p^n}/\Bbb{F}_p)\cong \Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$$
$$\therefore n \mid \phi(p^n-1)$$

Comment: Hmm. Something went wrong here. The ring $\Bbb{Z}_{p^n}$ has only $p^{n-1}(p-1)$ units. Did you mean to use the field of $p^n$ elements? Denoted either $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ or $GF(p^n)$. That, indeed, has $n$ field automorphisms that are thus also automorphism of its multiplicative group, which is cyclic of order $p^n-1$. Consequently you do get the claim from this.

Comment: *dou*. Yes, that is what I meant to do. Let me correct the spelling.

Comment: Ok. I'll check back. This is IMHO a creative way of doing it (if a bit overkill), so I will add an upvote after you fix it. Need to go for a quick bite now :-)

Comment: Thanks for checking on my notation again. I'm mixing things up sometimes.